# IEEE Interface Specification Standard

Tags: documentation, specifications, ieee

Does anyone know of a newer standard for software interface specifications than IEEE J-STD 16 1995?  I have been searching the web and the IEEE site and have not found anything, but may not be using the right combination of words in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all of the information that I have been able to gather, this is the best standard.  There are others out there or I could create my own format, but this one seems to be the most accepted....for anyone who wishes to know an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard that replaced J-STD-016-1995 was [IEEE 12207](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_12207).

The standards that defined the Software Life Cycle Process evolved in the following order:

1. [MIL-STD-2167](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-2167) (1988) & MIL-STD-7935A (1988)
2. [MIL-STD-498](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-498) (1994)
3. J-STD-016-1995 (1995)
4. [IEEE/EIA 12207](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_12207) (1998)

[Source](http://www.abelia.com/docs/122_016.pdf)